# Vue.js Disable page cache from router

Tags: vue.js

I'm new and I'm very sorry because there are many page of this argument, but I'm still stuck

when I compile the page (I am using yarn), the new page is loaded but I want see modify I do press ctrl+F5
This is not a problem for me but I can’t say at all, "if you want to see modify you do press ctrl+F5" ?

this is my router code **:**

```
routes: [
{
  path: '/',
  name: 'home',
  component: () => import('@/views/Home.vue'),
  meta: {
    resource: 'ACL',
    pageTitle: 'Home',
    breadcrumb: [
      {
        text: 'Home',
        active: true,
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

How can I do it in simple code when this page is never cached ?
Sorry for my ignorant

Comment: This may be an issue with your build config. Are you using vue-cli, webpack, or vite?

Comment: vue-cli i think, sorry

Comment: By default, the imported components should each have a content hash in the filename, something like `1023.83heje8e82d9.js`. If the content of the page changes, it should automatically load the new version because the content hash will be different. Did you happen to modify the webpack config at all?